# Running python script using shell in ansible, but cant seem to output stdout using print()

Tags: python, ansible

```
  shell: sleep 5; nohup python /tmp/rsync.py {{check}} {{source}} {{destination}} {{dest_host}} &
  register: status
  failed_when: "'FAILED' in status.stdout"
```

My playbook has something like the above snippet of code. And within the python script I have used print statements. But when I run and use debug stdout is empty. For debug I tried these two ways -

```
          - name: debug
            debug: var=status.stdout_lines
```

```
        - name: debug
          debug: msg={{ status.stdout }}
```

For printing to stdout I also used `sys.stdout.write` . Even this doesn't seem to work.
Achieved everything I need. Only this isn't working.
**Edit**: I have to run it in the background. Is there any new approach for handling this?

Comment: My output looks like this. ```ok: [target1] => {
    "status.stdout_lines": []
}```

Comment: Did you set the `export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` environment variable?

Comment: re-run the code using -vvvv and check if the shell module output. there would be stdout lines in it. check if it is empty or not ?

Comment: Since you run the script in the background, I could imagine Ansible has proceeded past the `status.stdout` part by the time the Python script itself actually prints something, and thus Ansible has not seen any output. Have you tried by not running the script in the background?

Comment: I haven't set any environmental variable. Using-vvvv prints empty lines. Running in background is working. But its necessary that I run it in BG mode. Any ideas on how to pull this off.

Comment: Try setting the PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 env variable.
this tells the script not to wait for a flush event, but to flush every print

Comment: @MenyIssakov `shell: sleep 5; export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 ; nohup python /tmp/rsync.py {{check}} {{source}} {{destination}} {{dest_host}} &`  also tried using TRUE instead of 1. nothing changed. please tell me if its implemented slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

Use async support from Ansible [[1]](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html)

Adjust value for async according to how much time your shell command takes to execute *(if it is five seconds, make async somewhat higher than 5)*

Adjust value for poll based on how frequently you want to check if the shell completed execution

```
- name: Execute shell
  shell: sleep 5; nohup python /tmp/rsync.py {{check}} {{source}} {{destination}} {{dest_host}}
  async: 100
  poll: 1
  register: status
  failed_when: "'FAILED' in status.stdout"
```

Comment: Will it cause any difference compared to when i run it in background mode using `&` . Because Its a necessity that run it in background. I'll try that once though.

Comment: In both situations Ansible runs your shell command using subprocess.Popen(). Async just provides to unblock the task and proceed or wait for job completion etc.